# Proof a mapping is convergent by Cauchy

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, proof-writing, proof-explanation

I want to prove the following is convergent by Cauchy, i.e. for any $\epsilon >0$, there is some $N$ such that for every $m \ge N$ and every $n\geq 0$, $|x_{m+n} - x_m| < \epsilon$.

Given:
$g$ maps the open interval $E$ into itself, $0 < k < 1$, $g$ is $k$-Lipschitz continuous, and
$x_0 \in E$.
Prove that the sequence $\{ x_k\}$ defined recursively by $x_k = g(x_{k−1})$ for $k \geq 1$
converges by Cauchy.

Proof:

The function $g$ is a contraction mapping if there exists a $k\in (0,1)$, such that
$$
|g(x)-g(y)|\le k|x-y|,
$$
for all $x,y\in[a,b]$.

Then
$$
|x_{n+1}-x_n|=|g(x_n)-g(x_{n-1})|\le k |x_n-x_{n-1}|
$$
and inductively
$$
|x_{n+1}-x_n|\le k |x_n-x_{n-1}|\le \cdots\le k^n |x_1-x_0|
$$

I am stuck here...

Comment: You're almost there! Use what you have obtained and the triangle inequality to bound $|x_{n+m}-x_n|$ for $m\geq 0$. You will want to recall $\sum_n k^n$ converges since $k\in (0,1)$.

Answer (score 1):

Fix $\varepsilon > 0$ and let $m, n \in \Bbb N$. By the triangle inequality, $$|x_{m+n} - x_n| \le \sum_{j = n}^{m+n-1} |x_{j+1} - x_j| \le \sum_{j = n}^{m+n-1} k^j|x_1 - x_0| \le \sum_{j = n}^\infty k^j|x_1 - x_0| = \frac{k^n}{1-k}|x_1 - x_0|$$ The last expression is less than $\varepsilon$ provided $n > \log_k(\frac{|x_1-x_0|}{1-k})$.